# Preview Image before and after capture

Tags: python, opencv, preview

I am running OpenCV 2.3.1 with PIL Python 2.7.5 on Debian Linux. I have this code that captures an image and saves it to a file. I have been able to automate it. But I would like a preview of the image before capture and also after capture while running the following code. Also the preview should be displayed for say 3 seconds but that can be achieved using time.sleep()

```
# capture an image
cv.NamedWindow('camera',cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0);

while True :
  image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
  # display webcam image
  cv.ShowImage('Raw', image)
  # handle events
  print 'capturing!'
  cv.SaveImage("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/test1.jpg",image)
  cv.DestroyAllWindows()
  break
```

Comment: Use an int variable as a counter and keep on incrementing it in the while loop, now, make that match with seconds using the information of frames, then, make sure, you come with a condition on that counter variable which will save image for every specific time interval in certain seconds or minutes or even hours, if you have a good math in your code. this would ve been my approach rather than worrying about timer and all

Comment: If you know how long you want to wait then why not just issue a `time.sleep(N)` where N is the number of seconds you want to wait? You can use a KeyboardInterrupt exception (traps ^C) to terminate the loop when you want to stop capturing.

Comment: @4nonymou5 what do you think now?